# Best approach for task scheduling. Android

Tags: android, kotlin

i am a little bit confused with what i should use to schedule tasks... My requirements for scheduled tasks are following:

1. Task has to be done once in a day/week/month
2. It can be more than one task with different schedules (for example 1 daily 2 weekly 1 monthly)
3. The task doesn't have to start at exact time, but for weekly or monthly schedule it has to start on the same day (specified by user).
4. Scheduled task must work after reboot

As for task itself - it is a simple background number calculations and notification.

From what i read, JobScheduler could be good for this if i wouldn't have 3rd requirement, because it will execute the task at any time OS see fits within specified time period.

I can do it with AlarmManager with exact time, but as i understand it is not a very good solution. Well at least Google doesn't recommend it.

Comment: Use Work Manager @Nick

Comment: I suggest you to use WorkManager for your case and in particular PeriodicWorkRequest class.